# DevStack Installation Error: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'PY2'

Tags: devstack

Attempting to install DevStack on CentOS 7. I updated everything on CentOS prior to installing DevStack. I'm getting this error but all indications is that I have the Python components installed.

if six.PY2:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'PY2'

This is the error line before the stack.sh errors out.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update `six`. First uninstall it by issuing

```
pip uninstall six
```

Then reinstall by issuing

```
pip install six
```

for an update to version 1.9